# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string - breaking wordpress template, needs to conform to PHP 7

Tags: php-7

I have an issue with the following line of code:

```
$this->$option['type']($option);
```

this line is taken from the following part

```
function render() 
{
    echo '<div class="wrap theme-settings-page">';

    foreach($this->options as $option) 
    {
        if (method_exists($this, $option['type'])) {
            $this->$option['type']($option);
        }       
    }
```

How do I alter/update this line of code to conform to PHP 7?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Yours,
Stephen

Comment: `$this->{$option['type']}($option)` should do the trick. The braces force `$option['type']` to be evaluated first, before its value is then used as the method name to call.

Comment: Genius! Fabulous, thanks:)